# "No module named " found when importing file that imports another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

So my directory currently looks something like this

`src
    \aws_resources
        \s3
           s3file.py
        util.py
test
    mytest.py`

I'm running the mytest.py file and it essentially imports the s3 file, while the s3 file imports the util.py file

My mytest.py says

`from src.aws_resources.s3 import *`

but when I run the test file I get an error

`ImportError: No module named aws_resources.util`

I tried adding

`from src.aws_resources import util` to mytest.py but I still get the same error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your current working directory is `test`, which means any `import` line will look into the `test` folder to find modules, if not found, go to the other paths existing in your `sys.path` (e.g. PYTHONPATH) to find.

Here are my two assumptions:

1.) `src` is not part of your PYTHONPATH
2.) In your `s3file.py` you have this line (or similar): `from aws_resources.util import *`

Since `aws_resources` is not a valid folder under `test`, and it couldn't be found under any of your `sys.path`, the Python interpreter couldn't find the module and rasied `ImportError`.

You can try one of the following:

1.) Restructure your folder structure so that everything can be immediately referenced from your current working directory.
2.) Handle the `from aws_resources.util import *` line in your `s3file.py` if you are importing it from another working directory.
3.) Add `src` into your PYTHONPATH, or move it to a folder identified in PATH/PYTHONPATH so you can always reference back to it.

The approach really depends on your use case for `src` and how often it gets referenced elsewhere.